# Collection View old icon doesn't get deselected

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

And I have to ask this as well. Been looking through the code for hours now and tried everything, but why does my old picture not get deselected? The user should be able to select one icon only. The selected icon is saved in Core Database. So this icon is also preselected when opening this view. However this item doesn't get deselected when he selects a new icon..why?

```
#import "IconSelectionCollectionViewController.h"
#import "IconSelectionCell.h"

@interface IconSelectionCollectionViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *icons;
@end


@implementation IconSelectionCollectionViewController

@synthesize mainCategory = _mainCategory;


#pragma mark Initialize model
- (void)setMainCategory:(MainCategory *)mainCategory
{
    //TODO
    _mainCategory = mainCategory;
    self.title = mainCategory.name;
}


#pragma mark View setup
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.collectionView registerClass:IconSelectionCell.class forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"IconCell"];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.icons = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"DefaultIcon", @"Car", @"Diploma", @"Earth", @"Flight", @"Home", @"Pen", @"Scooter", @"Ship", @"Train", nil];
    self.collectionView.allowsSelection = YES;
    self.collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = NO;
}


#pragma mark Data source delegate methods
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return self.icons.count;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *identifier = @"IconCell";

    IconSelectionCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.iconImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[self.icons objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    if([self.mainCategory.icon isEqualToString:[self.icons objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]){
        cell.selected = YES;
    }

    return cell;
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    return 1;
}

#pragma mark Collection View Delegate methods
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    self.mainCategory.icon = [self.icons objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}

#pragma mark – UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout

- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:
(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    CGSize itemSize;
    itemSize.height = 62;
    itemSize.width = 62;

    return itemSize;
}

- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:
(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 10, 10);
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not incredibly familiar with collection views, but they are very similar to table views and this is a problem that sometimes occurs with UITableviews, so I will work through a couple possible solutions.

One way to do this would be to call [self.collectionView reloadData] after the selection code.  This should cause the collectionView to redraw the images, setting only one of them to be the selected image.

However, I'm not confident this would solve the problem, since dequeue reusable cells could cause the "selection" value to be set for the reused cell.  So alternatively, I'd imagine you could grab both cells using UICollectionView's method cellForItemAtIndexPath: and then set their selected value in the way you set them in the main method.  That may just work, but if it does not, try doing that and calling reload data again.